# Unable to transfer eth into contract in hardhat

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, payable, waffle

I am working on some ERC20 tokens in which user have to send it to get tokens,
i am getting some error while running it!!

i am stuck at the

```
const txHash = await addr1.sendTransaction({
      to: Contract_address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
    });
```

getting an long error :

```
 Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback nor receive function", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8","to":"0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0de0b6b3a7640000"}............
```

Here is the code :

1. ERC20Token.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract INR is ERC20 {

    mapping(address => uint256) _balancesETH;
    uint256 public initailPrice;
    address public owner;

    constructor(uint256 price) ERC20("Golden", "GLD") {
        initailPrice = price;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {  
        address owner_S = _msgSender();
        uint256 percentage = 350; // 3% of per 10,000 eg: 300 is of 3%

        uint256 value = percentageCalculate(percentage, amount);
        value = value >=100 ? value / 100 : value / 10 ;
        _burn(msg.sender, value);
        uint256 valuetoRecevier = amount - value;
        console.log("Value Recevied by recevier is :");
        console.log(valuetoRecevier);
        _transfer(owner_S, to, valuetoRecevier);
        return true;
    }

    function percentageCalculate(uint256 percentageInBasePoints, uint256 amountValue) public pure returns(uint256){
        // base point means 3% is 300 and 3.5% is 350
        uint256 newFormula;
        if(amountValue >= 100){
              newFormula = percentageInBasePoints * ((amountValue) / 100 );

        } else {
          //  amountValue = amountValue / 10;
          percentageInBasePoints /= 10;
            newFormula  = (percentageInBasePoints * (amountValue)) / 100;
            
        }
        return newFormula;
    }   

    function getEthtoToken() payable external returns(bool){
        console.log("Initial Price is :-");
        console.log(initailPrice); 

        uint256 ETHrecevied = msg.value;

        _balancesETH[msg.sender] = ETHrecevied;

        uint256 noETH = ETHrecevied / 1000000000000000; // 10^15 

        console.log("ETH recevied in finney(milliether) :-");
        console.log(noETH);

        uint256 priceCalulate = (initailPrice * noETH )/ 1000; 

        console.log("Numbers of tokens will be transfer :-");
        console.log(priceCalulate);

            _mint(msg.sender, priceCalulate);

            uint256 getSupply = initailPrice / 10;
            initailPrice -= getSupply; 

            console.log("Initial Price will be :-");
            console.log(initailPrice); 

            payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
            return true;
    }

    // receive() external payable {
    //     _balancesETH[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    //     getEthtoToken();
    // }

    // fallback() external payable {
    //     // React to receiving ether
    //     _balancesETH[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    //     // getEthtoToken();
    // }
}
```

here is my testcase file
2.sample-test.js :

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, waffle } = require("hardhat");

describe("Token", function () {
  it("Deploy and run functions to get token", async function () {
    // 
    const provider = waffle.provider;
    const [owner1, addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4] = await ethers.getSigners();

    //
    const ERC20Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("INR");
    const Token = await ERC20Token.deploy(100);
    await Token.deployed();
    const Contract_address = await Token.address;
    console.log("address of contract : "+Contract_address);

    expect(await Token.initailPrice()).to.equal(100);

    //
    const owner_address = await Token.owner();
    console.log("Deployer address : "+owner_address);

    expect(await owner_address).to.equal(owner1.address);

    const Owner_Balance = await provider.getBalance(owner_address);
    ethers.utils.formatEther(Owner_Balance)
    console.log("Balance of Owner is : "+Owner_Balance);

    
   
    const addr1_balance = await provider.getBalance(addr1.address);
    console.log("balance of address 1 before transaction : "+ethers.utils.formatEther(addr1_balance));


    const txHash = await addr1.sendTransaction({
      to: Contract_address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
    });

    console.log(txHash);
    // const params = { to: addr2.address, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0").toHexString()};
    // const txHash = await addr1.sendTransaction(params);
    // console.log("transactionHash is " + txHash);  

    const addr1_balance2 = await provider.getBalance(addr1.address);
    console.log("Balance of address 1 after transaction : "+ethers.utils.formatEther(addr1_balance2));

    const ethToToken = await Token.getEthtoToken();
    // wait until the transaction is mined
    await ethToToken.wait();

    const balanceOfContract = await provider.getBalance(Contract_address);
    console.log("Balance of contract is : "+ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceOfContract));
    console.log("Balance of Contract owner is : "+ethers.utils.formatEther(Owner_Balance)); 

  });
});
```

Comment: When you call `sendTransaction` without data, it will trigger `receive()` or `fallback()` but they are all commented out. I think you just need to uncomment one of them.

Comment: i want to use the payable function `function getEthtoToken() payable external returns(bool){` which is in my contract

Comment: I think you should call `Token.getEthtoToken()` in that case?

Comment: can i use override params here like `Token.getEthtoToken({from: addr1, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"), })` like these or how should  i ??

Comment: hey thanks for help i have solved the issue by using this code
`const sendEth = await Token.connect(addr1).getEthtoToken({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")});

    // wait until the transaction is mined
     await sendEth.wait();`

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the update.

Comment: @DereK Please, add the solution as an answer so the question can be marked as resolved! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Way of sending eth through payable functions in hardhat testcases.

```
const sendEth = await Token.connect(addr1).getEthtoToken({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")});      // wait until the transaction is mined      await sendEth.wait();
```